# Проблема смены раскладки в Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android

Здравствуйте!

Постоянно такой косяк случается: набираю код, частенько меняю раскладку, и в какой-то момент она не хочет меняться обратно. Только при работе в Android studio.
Работаю под Windows`ом. Презапускаю среду, и все хорошо работает. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 10):

На последних, на текущую дату, версиях *Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA* мне не удалось воспроизвести данную проблему из чего можно подумать, что ее пофиксили.

Для ценителей раритетов или по другим причинам не имеющих возможности обновиться, существует очень простое решение:

В настройках переключения раскладок клавиатуры операционной системы повесить дополнительные комбинации на принудительное включение требуемых раскладок и пользоваться этими комбинациями, вместо <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

**Для Windows8**

<kbd>Панель управления</kbd> -> <kbd>Язык</kbd> -> <kbd>Дополнительные параметры</kbd> -> <kbd>Переключение методов ввода</kbd> -> <kbd>Изменить сочетание клавиш языковой панели</kbd>

Появится окно: *Языки и службы текстового ввода*.
Выбираете пункт: *Включить Английский* и нажимаете <kbd>Сменить сочетание клавиш</kbd>
Указываете удобное вам сочетание на ВКЛЮЧЕНИЕ английской раскладки.
То же самое делаете для русской раскладки.

В процессе работы пользуетесь обретенными комбинациями для ВКЛЮЧЕНИЯ нужной раскладки, а не переключения между ними.

[image: screen]