# Не включается английская раскладка в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Здравствуйте. У меня проблема. Перевёл на ноутбуке раскладку на английскую. А в студии все пишет на русском. Как лечить?

Comment: Эту проблему вроде давно побороли, но [вот решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455719/177345)

Comment: Перезапустил студию и все заработало))